# Почему класс не наследуется от прототипа?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Мой код:

```js
'use strict';

class Bicycle {
    constructor(productionYear, speedNum, wheelDiameter){
        this.productionYear = productionYear;
        this.speedNum = speedNum;
        this.wheelDiameter = wheelDiameter;
    }
}

class LTDGravity990_29 extends Bicycle {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
let LTD = new LTDGravity990_29(2018,20,29);
console.log(LTD)
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: В консоли должны выводиться конкретные значения: 
  "productionYear": 2018,
  "speedNum": 20,
  "wheelDiameter": 29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс "наследуется" от прототипа.

И это доказывает вывод:

```
{
  "productionYear": undefined,
  "speedNum": undefined,
  "wheelDiameter": undefined
}
```

То есть, у созданного объекта присутствуют все необходимые свойства.

---

Значения свойствам присваивается в конструкторе. За вызов конструктора базового класса отвечает `super`.

Так как `super` вызывается **без параметров**, это равносильно вызову с передачей каждому из параметров значение `undefined`.

Для решения, необходимо просто передать значения в вызов `super`, например так:

```js
'use strict';

class Bicycle {
  constructor(productionYear, speedNum, wheelDiameter) {
    this.productionYear = productionYear;
    this.speedNum = speedNum;
    this.wheelDiameter = wheelDiameter;
  }
}

class LTDGravity990_29 extends Bicycle {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
let LTD = new LTDGravity990_29(2018, 20, 29);
console.log(LTD)
```